# unique id generation for all DB vendors

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have a project which is developed using hibernate- jpa annoatation.

I have chance to create id using JPA which are AUTO, Increment, sequence and table.

Auto is working fine for all DB vendors but, it increase the id for all table together.

Ex: Table a - id is 100

table b id is 101.

c id is 102.

i wanna have ids like

For table A id should be 100 to 1000

For table B id should be 100 to 1000

for all tables also.

I don't want to create separate sequence & Table and make DB fill.

Answer (score 1):

AUTO doesn't increment the ID for all the tables together.

Here's what it does (from the JPA specification):

> The AUTO value indicates that the persistence provider should pick an
>   appropriate strategy for the particular database. The AUTO generation
>   strategy may expect a database resource to exist, or it may attempt to
>   create one. A vendor may provide documentation on how to create such
>   resources in the event that it does not support schema generation or
>   cannot create the schema resource at runtime.

If you care about the strategy that should be used, then define an explicit strategy, and the database resources needed by this strategy.